# Google Earth Engine Python API Filter.or Invalid Snytax

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to filter a MODIS image collection for two date ranges with the Python API of Google Earth Engine, but I'm encountering the following problem.

In the JavaScript Google Code Editor, I would do something like this:

```js
var modis1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1');
var rng1= ee.Filter.date('2019-02-01','2019-06-30');
var rng2 = ee.Filter.date('2020-02-01','2020-06-30');
var rngor = ee.Filter.or(rng1,rng2);
var modisfiltered = modis1.filter(rngor);
```

And this would work. In Python, instead, the code stops on the `ee.Filter.or` line because of an `"Invalid Syntax"` error.

Is it because `or` is a reserved keyword in Python?

How can I obtain the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing `help(ee.Filter)` in the Python console shows that the Python API uses `ee.Filter.Or`, with a capital "O".

That's the first time that the integrate help function helps me more than a help search though, Google Earth Engine API online documentation is pretty lacking on Python syntax details.